# CSS Typing Animation Changes Text Placement

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I incorporated Bootstrap on my site to make it responsive. I also added in CSS animation to my code. However, this takes the text from being in the center of the page, to starting on the far left of the page, finishing the animation, and then shifting the text to the center.

How do I start the animation in the center itself?

Bootstrap Code:

```
<header id="top" class="header">
    <div class="text-vertical-center">

        <h1 class="css-typing">Hi, welcome to my website.</h1>
        <h3 class="css-typing">Let's get started.</h3>
        <br>
        <a href="#about" class="btn btn-primary">Let's Get Started.</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS Code:

```
.css-typing
{
    width: 100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-animation: type 3s steps(50, end);
    animation: type 3s steps(50, end)1;
}

@keyframes type{
    from { width: 0; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes type{
    from { width: 0;  }
}
```

Any thoughts or help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no `.css-typing` class in your markup. Please update this fiddle to show your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/quL9kr60/

Comment: Updated the class in the markup. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 3):

Put the animated texts into a `<span>`, this span will be has the class `typing` instead:

```
<h1><span class="typing">Hi, welcome to my website.</span></h1>
<h3><span class="typing">Let's get started.</span></h3>
```

and add `display: inline-block;` for the `typing` class:

```
.typing
{
    ...
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ctedopow/1/

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! Can you explain why that did the fix, for future reference?

Thanks!

Comment: What the "typing" animation does is: set the element's width to 0 originally, then increase the width step-by-step until it reach 100% width. The `h1` and `h3` elements are `block` elements, and stick to the left side of its container by default. I don't want to change that behavior, so I put the text into `span` - which is an `inline` element by default. Inline elements are considered text content, so they are centered within the container by `text-align: center;`. `display: inline-block;` is a little tweak to allow the span's width to become editable.